# meaning of quotient topology in munkres book

Tags: general-topology

I can't understand quotient topology  in Munkres' book
it says at page 137 :$p$ from $X$ to $Y$  a quotient map  is equivalent to saying that $p$ is continuous & $p$ maps saturated open sets of $X$ to open sets of $Y$.

i know the definitions but i cant understand this equivalency.

please explain it!

thanks a lot!

Comment: usually in an equivalence there are two directions: which one is more problematic to you?

Comment: i understand none of them!

Comment: are you sure to know the definitions? could you edit with the definitions you are using?

Answer (score 5):

The quotient map is defined as follows :- $p:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a quotient map if it is surjective and $U\subset Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Let $p$ be a quotient map. We need to show that it maps saturated open sets to open sets. Let $V\subset X$ be a saturated open set. Then $V=p^{-1}(p(V))$ and $p$ being the quotient map implies that $p(V)$ is open in $Y$.

Now assume the converse. Clearly $p$ is a continuous map. So all we need to show is that if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ for $U\subset Y$, then $U$ must be open in $Y$. But $p^{-1}(U)$ is a saturated set which is open also hence by the hypothesis $p(p^{-1}(U))=U$ must be open in $Y$ and which shows the equivalence of the two definitions.

Comment: maybe you could add the argument why $p^{-1}[U]$ is saturated?

Comment: thnks a lot Henno Brandsma!

Comment: thnks a lot wanderer!

Comment: thnks wanderer but i cant understand why p-1(U) is saturated?

Comment: @user115608 recall the definition of saturated set : A set $U\subset X$ is said to be saturated in $X$ if $U=p^{-1}(V)$ for some $V\subset Y$.

Comment: wanderer but munkres says:C is saturated if it contains every previous image whiche has nonempty intersection with C.

Comment: @user115608 exactly, it contains every pre image which has non-empty intersection with it, i.e., it is a complete pre-image of any set, because whatever pre-image intersects with $C$, it contains it.